# How to show graphs in Jupyter-notebook, all other solutions did not work

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am taking a machine learning course, the code is being implemented with jupyter notebook.

Problem description:
It does not show the graph, that I intented to see.

Solutions applied:
Using; %matplotlib inline, %matplotlib under the import line, show() is used as it is suggested in this site: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_plotting.htm

My code: (each line means a different line in the notebook)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv("udemy machine learning/homeprices.csv")
df

plt.xlabel('Area(sqr ft)')
plt.ylabel('Price(US$)')
plt.scatter(df.Area, df.Price, color= 'red', marker = '+')

plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edited:**
Dataframe works fine, the data is ok.

Comment: show some dataframe rows.

Comment: @inquirer the dataframe shows its values there is no problem with that.

Comment: if you don't use Jupyter-notebook, the graph is drawn?

Comment: @inquirer, I did not try anything on other platforms.